# How to refresh a php page after click save?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, refresh, page-refresh

I have a page form to edit, with submit button 'save'. I want my page to automatically refresh to show the modifications, after clicking save. But I want it to refresh only if I click save not automatically after a delay. Just one time, no need to refresh every x seconds!

```
if (isset($_POST['ajout'])) {
        $travail = str_replace("'","&#039", $_POST['travail']);
        $req = $fun -> modifier($_POST['name'], $travail);
        if ($req) {
            echo '
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        document.getElementById("merci").style.display = "none";
                    },10000);
                </script>
                <div id="merci" class="alert alert-success fade in">
                    <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close close-sm" type="button">
                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                    </button>
                    success
                </div>
            ';
        } else {
            echo '
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        document.getElementById("merci").style.display = "none";
                    },10000);
                </script>
                <div id="merci" class="alert alert-danger fade in">
                    <button data-dismiss="alert" class="close close-sm" type="button">
                        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                    </button>
                    <strong>erro</strong> try aagain
                </div>
            ';
        }
}
```

Comment: What does the code you posted do? It doesn't seem to contain any sort of form...

Comment: this is the php code of saving data to insert it in database . what i am looking for is how to refresh my page after saving data for once time not refreshing every x number of seconds

Comment: Do you use JS to submit the form? Do you use a button with the `submit`-type to to submit the form? If you use a button and just post to the site, that reloads it

Comment: i use button type submit ! but how i insert a script  inside the  ' if ($req) {  '  to reload my page

Comment: your page already reloads on submit. You could always use `window.location.reload()`

Comment: yes i used it but it reload a page in a recursive way each a number of seconds but me i just use it for once time only when i submit then it stop ! that what i am looking for from the beggining